# Clojure merge key values in hash map

Tags: clojure

So I have the below hash map of k/v:

```
(def data [{:ID "0000010890" :CREDIT "EM 1"}

{:ID "0000010890" :CREDIT "FLOW 1"}

{:ID "0000010890" :CREDIT "EM 1"}

{:ID "0000010890" :CREDIT "FLOW 1"}

{:ID "0000010809" :CREDIT "FLOW 1"}])
```

which I need to merge in to this:

```
[{:ID "0000010890" :CREDIT "EM 1, FLOW 1"}

{:ID "0000010809" :CREDIT "FLOW 1"}]
```

Can anyone advise the best way to go about this in clojure?

My attempt:

```
(defn- create-issue-summary-2 [data]
            (->> data
                 (group-by :ID)
                 (map (fn [[k v]] (into {:ID k} (apply merge-with (map #(dissoc % :ID) v)))))))
```

Which results in

```
({:ID "0000010890", :CREDIT "FLOW 1"}
```

{:ID "0000010809"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(map (fn [[k v]]
       (into {} [[:ID k]
                 [:CREDIT (apply str (interpose ", " (distinct (map :CREDIT v))))]]))
     (group-by :ID data))
```